# Ruby on rails testing - table X has no column named Y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to write some basic Rails test code using the default rails testing framework. My application is for a simple forum, where users can post threads, comment etc.

I am trying to test the forum (i.e. a thread) controller, here it is:

forums_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ForumsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 test "index should be success" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
 end
end
```

I am using fixtures and am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wIta0fITzc

Here are all my fixture files:

comments.yml

```
comm_one:
  body: MyText
  forum_id: 1

comm_two:
  body: MyText
  forum_id: 2
```

forums.yml

```
for_one:
  title: MyString
  body: MyText
  user_id: 1

for_two:
  title: MyString
  body: MyText
  user_id: 2
```

users.yml

```
user_one: 
  user_id: '1'

user_two: 
  user_id: '2'
```

The issue i am having is that when i run `rake` in the terminal, I get this error:

`Error:
ForumsControllerTest#test_index_should_be_success:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "users" has no column named "user_id".`

Not sure if you need to see my migrate files, but if you need any other information, let me know.

I would be grateful for any advice.

Thanks

NOTE: I am using the devise gem for my user authentication. This was used to generate the users table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by first following Tisamu's advice on replacing user_id with just id. Then i added user emails to the user file to make it like so:

```
user_one: 
  id: 1
  email: 'a@a.com'

user_two: 
  id: 2
  email: 'b@b.com'
```

This solved the issue with any code. But i then got a error message saying this:

```
Error:
ForumsControllerTest#test_index_should_be_success:
ActionView::Template::Error: Devise could not find the `Warden::Proxy` instance on your request environment.
Make sure that your application is loading Devise and Warden as expected and that the `Warden::Manager` middleware is present in your middleware stack.
If you are seeing this on one of your tests, ensure that your tests are either executing the Rails middleware stack or that your tests are using the `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` module to inject the `request.env['warden']` object for you.
    app/views/forums/index.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_forums_index_html_erb___3974819143402431947_37087120'
    app/views/forums/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_forums_index_html_erb___3974819143402431947_37087120'
    test/controllers/forums_controller_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:ForumsControllerTest>'
```

I fixed this by simply adding `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` to my test file to make it like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ForumsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers # <-- Have to include this
 test "index should be success" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in the structure the tables, the Users would not have a user_id column but just an id one, if another models has one User, or belongs to a User, then that model would have a user_id column to get the corresponding User.
Look at the doc to understand the structure you must have in your database: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks, i changed, user_id to id and this led me to solving the problem (after solving some other issues)

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use full power of Rails fixtures:

```
-----comments.yml----

comm_one:
  body: MyText
  forum: for_one

comm_two:
  body: MyText
  forum: for_two

---- forums.yml-----

for_one:
  title: MyString
  body: MyText
  user: user_one

for_two:
  title: MyString
  body: MyText
  user: user_two

----- users.yml -----

user_one: 
  email: 'a@a.com'

user_two: 
  email: 'a@b.com'
```